# How to keep this skip in memory GoTo Next Iteration in For Loop in java

Tags: java

I am wondering how can you keep this iteration in memory.
**I forgot to say that player one can choose any of the five button**
I was just using button 1 as a example for player 1.
this is where my problem is cause I can't figure out a way to keep this chosen button which can be any to stay disable(false) after player 2 as chosen is button.

It works if I don't disable all button after player 1 chose is, but the other 4 are enable and if player 1 press one of those button when its player 2 turns everything is mess up.

that's what I'm trying to fix. Help please.

I have 5 button for player 1 and 5 button for player 2.
Let's say button 1 is press for player 1, after its press all the other button is deactivated for player 1 and the others are activated for player 2

When player 2 press it chooses is button, all other of his is deactivated

Here is the tricky part, after player 2 press his button, player 1 button reactivate minus button 1 which was already chosen. This means only 2,3,4 and 5 are activated.

and so on. This must alternate until all 5 button was chosen.
I just can't seem to find, its the tricky part that I can't figure out.
Can anyone help me solve this or any suggestion.
Thanks.

here is the code

```
//The 2 first for loop are for just showing the 10 buttons 
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
         x=100*i;
         jbChoixJun[i]=new JButton(String.valueOf("Choisir"));
         jbChoixJun[i].setBounds(x+30,160,80,30);
         add(jbChoixJun[i]);
         jbChoixJun[i].addActionListener(this); 
         jbChoixJun[i].setEnabled(false);           
     }

     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
         x=100*i;
         jbChoixJdeux[i]=new JButton(String.valueOf("Choisir"));
         jbChoixJdeux[i].setBounds(x+30,390,80,30);
         add(jbChoixJdeux[i]);
         jbChoixJdeux[i].addActionListener(this); 
         jbChoixJdeux[i].setEnabled(false);
     }
 //The next 2 for loop, when the player its the button it becomes false and
 // stay false until the end, this works ok
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(source==jbChoixJun[i])
            {
                mainJoueur1.getCarte(compteurI1);
                jbChoixJun[i].setEnabled(false);

                compteur1=1;
                compteurI1=i;
                comparaison1=true;
                System.out.println("compteur des images");
                System.out.println("compteurI1="+compteurI1);
                comparaisonBataille1=true;

            }
            //This turn all button off after the player chose is
            if(jbChoixJun[compteurI1].isEnabled()==false)
                jbChoixJun[i].setEnabled(false);
        }


        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(source==jbChoixJdeux[i])
            {
                mainJoueur2.getCarte(compteurI2);
                jbChoixJdeux[i].setEnabled(false);
                compteur2=1;
                compteurI2=i;
                comparaison2=true;
                comparaisonBataille2=true;

                jbChoixJun[compteurI1].setEnabled(false);   
            }
            if(jbChoixJdeux[compteurI1].isEnabled()==false)
                jbChoixJdeux[i].setEnabled(false);
            if(i==compteurI1)
                continue;
            else
                jbChoixJun[i].setEnabled(true);
```

The problem, is that the first button chosen by player comes active and only the  second one that becomes disable.
Can of hard to explain
Hope you guys can help me

Comment: Don't you just want a 2D array?  boolean[2][5] will hold all your data, then you just need to code up your action listener to implement the rules of your game.

Comment: didn't think about that one. I'll try and see. I gues I'll have to create a 2d boolean array for this to work. I just thought that with a iterator would of work. thanks

Comment: Why don't you create a class which will extend JButton and add additional boolean properties to it, and use them accordingly.

Comment: mmm, i see. I'm not that good in java. I can create this class your talking about, but just can't see if I can make it work. Thanks for the tip, I'll try and see what can i make out of it.

Comment: I have done similar program recently and made it work by extending the Button class.

Comment: cool. I'll see what i can do. I guess a have just to create class and extend it to my class that as my jbutton in it

Comment: dunno't know what to say I just can't see what I can do with a new class. I feel stupid, just can't see the picture. I guess it's one of those days

Comment: Just one question, my mind is not thinking straight. If I make a new class, how can I relate the JButton already created to it or ...I know it extends but  just don't see the picture can you give just a starter. I know I'll have to create a array in the new class, just can't see how to relate it to the JButton I already have

Comment: thanks Hugh, i was 2 boolean arrays. One for each player but with a for loop in each for loop already describe above with go to next iterator did the tricks thanks. I would of posted a answer but I doesn't let me so feel free to ask me if you want more details of the code.

Answer (score 0):

As asked by the OP here is how you can extend JButton and use it according to your needs by adding new properties, this gives you more flexibility

```
public class ExtendedJButton extends JButton{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * We use this boolean for some case and set it to true or false according to out need
     */
    private boolean someCheck;

    //Add more propterties according to your need and create conditions to enable and disable them accordingly

    public boolean isSomeCheck() {
        return someCheck;
    }

    public void setSomeCheck(boolean someCheck) {
        this.someCheck = someCheck;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frameForExample = new JFrame();
        ExtendedJButton button = new ExtendedJButton();
        frameForExample.add(button);

        //Now you can access properties of JButton class as well as new properties of your extended class
        button.setEnabled(false);
        ////.........

        //An example case
        if(button.isSomeCheck()){
            //Do what you want to
            //if you want to disable the button when this case is true do it, 
        }
    }
```

This is not an answer but more a guidance on how you can proceed.

Comment: I see a little more clearer, but just don't get the big picture. I'm trying to understand what you are doing.  I just can't. In the example case, I can enable or disable any button I want, and it will stay that way until it's call for a different boolean action

Comment: What I am trying to say is you can add new booleans to this button class and then you when, you need to enable the button can check whether this button can be enabled or not by checking the other boolean values which you set when your player does different actions.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand. Do I use this extended class for my new button for all ten of them?

Comment: Well see this was just an idea, if you have 10 buttons yeah you will use the same class for those 10 buttons. What I am trying to convery is the extra boolean variables which you define, you can use them and enable and disable your button accordingly. Lets say you want to enable you buttons if all those booleans are true, so you will when going in enable button loop in your code will check the booleans and enable the buttons if needed. You can add other variables too like times clicked etc inside this extended jButton and modify it accordingly

Comment: sorry, but i just can't see it. cause I have 5 button for player 1 and 5 button  for player 2. I just can't  see how to do this with this extended class to call. I'll have to create all ten button with this new class if I understand

Comment: and I tried it and I have to change all my boardlayout cause it doesn't do the same with the new class

Comment: I think I won't be able to explain this in more details as it is hard here. Sorry all I can say is think of this ExtendedJButton class as a normal JButton with additional features. Quite Strange if it doesn't work I can't explain here Sorry.

Comment: i think its because I'm not using JFrame. I don't want to recode everything just tough there was a simple way of doing it. thanks for your help

Comment: I think you should read more about OOP concepts before starting Swing as I can see your OOP knowledge is very limited.

Comment: it is. but you don't need to use JFrame, i'm using gridlayout with borderlayout north, south and so on. Just started like 2 weeks ago so I'm learning.

Comment: I used jframe just to give you an example on how you will add the buttoms of this new class to whatever place you want to.

Comment: cool, well I.m trying with the first 5 set of button and my button are in the right place so far so good

Comment: So now i just fix my methods in my extended class?

Comment: Can you give me just one more example of one properties that I can use in the extended class, not really sure how to do so

Comment: Well it depends on what really you want to achieve with your program. If you want to check if button was wasLastPressed, you can have boolean for same and enable disable it accordingly. So when a different button is pressed you can change the wasLastPressed boolean acordingly.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have finally found a solution. Just created 2 boolean arrays for each player and then with a for loop with code did the trick. thanks again

Comment: I really like your idea of the extended class, but I had to solve this as soon as possible. But let say lastPress, i just can't figure out what to put in it.  I would really like to understand your way of the extended class

Comment: You will understand what I mean by experience. So don't think about it much, just read more about OOP concepts.

Comment: ok thanks, well my program was built with OOP, just that sometimes I don't find the right formula to put in it. Thanks for you help, it was greatly appreciated